# void* as unknown variable type

Tags: c++, void

I'm currently working on a sprite engine in C++. I have an abstract class IEngine with a virtual function init_api.  This takes in a void*.

```
    //  Initialise the engines' API
//  api_params - void* to api parameters for initalisation
//  hWnd - window handle
virtual bool init_api( void* api_params, HWND hWnd ) = 0;
```

I then have a DirectX implemented engine class CEngineDX.  Which then casts api_params to a D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS*, so it can be used for initialising DirectX.

```
//  Cast api_params to a D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS* presentParams = NULL;
presentParams = reinterpret_cast< D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS* >( api_params );
```

I'm quite happy with this setup but wanted to get some other programmers view on this "solution" if you like.

Cheers for the replies!

Carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it is just have a common header and different *.cpp files for each implementation.  That way you can include just the D3D or just the OGL files in your project.  IMO its better to choose the API at compile time so your not linking against both libraries.

As for the void*, I don't really like it.  I think you'd be better off defining your own types and then mapping them to the API types with wrapper structs / classes and typedefs.  You can forward declare these, and put the actual implementation in your *.cpp files.

One other benefit of this method is that your not paying for virtual functions you don't need, although I realize the cost of a virtual call is pretty small.

Answer (score 1):

This is a relatively common problem with the variation of argument types in inheritance hierarchies; your subclass wants to specialize the type of 'api_params' from the parent class.

I think this is OK but it is C-like. I think better solution would be to make `init_api` non-virtual and implement it with the correct type in the subclass. Anyway, most likely the `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS` struct makes only sense with the DirectX engine, so why not have it in the subclass where it logically belongs to?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use templates (is you dislike casts), but your hierarchy will have to go in that case.

```
template<class T>
struct Engine {
   bool init_api(const T& params, HWND hWnd);
};

//specialize for DirectX
template<>
struct Engine <D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS> {
  bool init_api(const D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS& params, HWND hWnd) {
    return true;
  }
};
```

But, use something that fits into the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like this API. Why use a void pointer? Why not make the first parameter a pointer or reference to `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS`? You know that is what it should be anyway right? This is more type-safe.